# Fast way combine multiple columns of type float into one column of type array(float)

Tags: pandas

I have a dataset like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "333-0": [123,123,123],
    "5985-0.0": [1,2,3],
    "5985-0.1":[1,2,3],
    "5985-0.2":[1,2,3]  
     },
     index = [0,1,2] )
```

Here, we have three columns `["5985-0.0", "5985-0.1", "5985-0.2"]` that represent the first, second and third float readings of thing `5985-0` -- i.e. `.x` represents an array index.

I'd like to take multiple columns and collapse them into a single column `5985-0` containing some kind of list of float, which I can do like this:

```
srccols = ["5985-0.0", "5985-0.1", "5985-0.2"]
df["5985-0"] = df[srccols].apply(tuple, axis=1)
df.dropna(srccols, axis=1)

   333-0     5985-0
0    123  (1, 1, 1)
1    123  (2, 2, 2)
2    123  (3, 3, 3)
```

which I can then store as an SQL table with an array column.

However, apply(tuple) is very slow. Is there a faster, more idiomatic pandas way to combine multiple columns into one.

(First person to say "normalized" gets a downvote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***My Choice***
*Assuming I know the columns*

```
thing = '5985-0'
cols = ['5985-0.0', '5985-0.1', '5985-0.2']
k = len(cols)
v = df.values
l = [v[:, df.columns.get_loc(c)].tolist() for c in cols]
s = pd.Series(list(zip(*l)), name=thing)
df.drop(cols, 1).join(s)

   333-0     5985-0
0    123  (1, 1, 1)
1    123  (2, 2, 2)
2    123  (3, 3, 3)
```

***Base Case***
Using `filter`, `join`, and `apply(tuple, 1)`

```
thing = '5985-0'
d = df.filter(like=thing)
s = d.apply(tuple, 1).rename(thing)
cols = d.columns
df.drop(cols, 1).join(s)

   333-0     5985-0
0    123  (1, 1, 1)
1    123  (2, 2, 2)
2    123  (3, 3, 3)
```

***Option 2***
*Using `filter`, `join`, `pd.Series`*

```
thing = '5985-0'
d = df.filter(like=thing)
s = pd.Series(d.values.tolist(), name=thing)
cols = d.columns
df.drop(cols, 1).join(s)

   333-0     5985-0
0    123  [1, 1, 1]
1    123  [2, 2, 2]
2    123  [3, 3, 3]
```

***Option 3***
*Using `filter`, `join`, `pd.Series`, and `zip`*

```
thing = '5985-0'
d = df.filter(like=thing)
s = pd.Series(list(zip(*d.values.T)), name=thing)
cols = d.columns
print(df.drop(cols, 1).join(s))  
   333-0     5985-0
0    123  (1, 1, 1)
1    123  (2, 2, 2)
2    123  (3, 3, 3)
```

---

***Timing***
*Large Data Set*

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True

%%timeit
thing = '5985-0'
d = df.filter(like=thing)
s = d.apply(tuple, 1).rename(thing)
cols = d.columns
df.drop(cols, 1).join(s)
1 loop, best of 3: 350 ms per loop

%%timeit
thing = '5985-0'
cols = ['5985-0.0', '5985-0.1', '5985-0.2']
k = len(cols)
v = df.values
l = [v[:, df.columns.get_loc(c)].tolist() for c in cols]
s = pd.Series(list(zip(*l)), name=thing)
df.drop(cols, 1).join(s)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.06 ms per loop

%%timeit
thing = '5985-0'
d = df.filter(like=thing)
s = pd.Series(d.values.tolist(), name=thing)
cols = d.columns
df.drop(cols, 1).join(s)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.56 ms per loop

%%timeit
thing = '5985-0'
d = df.filter(like=thing)
s = pd.Series(list(zip(*d.values.T)), name=thing)
cols = d.columns
df.drop(cols, 1).join(s)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.89 ms per loop
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks - is a very comprehensive set of better options. Though I'm totally confused about where the speedup comes from. Compared to my original apply and tuple, its seems various steps in your solutions also escape the C internals and call into python (list, zip, ...). Perhaps apply just has a very slow implementation?

Comment: @user48956 `zip` is quite zippy.  `apply` is a glorified `for` loop.  `d.values.tolist()` should be totally vectorized but `zip` is still faster.  You can get good performance from `zip` and comprehensions.