# How to find elements of series containing a list?

Tags: pandas

I can find Series cells matching tuples...

```
>>> s = pd.Series([(1,2,3),(4,5,6)], index=[1,2])
>>> print s[s==(1,2,3)]
1    (1, 2, 3)
dtype: object
```

How do I do the same for lists:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], index=[1,2])
>>> print s[s==[1,2,3]]
ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 2 vs 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Easy Approach***

```
s[s.apply(tuple) == (1, 2, 3)]

1    [1, 2, 3]
dtype: object
```

***Less Easy***
*Assumes all sub-lists are the same length*

```
def contains_list(s, l):
    a = np.array(s.values.tolist())
    return (a == l).all(1)

s[contains_list(s, [1, 2, 3])]

1    [1, 2, 3]
dtype: object
```

---

***Timing***
*Assume a larger series*

```
s = pd.Series([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] * 1000)

%timeit s[pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index).isin([1,2,3]).all(1)]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.22 ms per loop

%timeit s[contains_list(s, [1, 2, 3])]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.01 ms per loop

%timeit s[s.apply(tuple) == (1, 2, 3)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.07 ms per loop
```

Comment: The downside of this is that its shockingly slow -- see your answer here :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43771114/fast-way-combine-multiple-columns-of-type-float-into-one-column-of-type-arrayfl/43771182#43771182

Comment: I tried to find an alternative non-complicated approach and ... i couldn't ;-)

Comment: @user48956 I'm not shocked that is so slow.  Sorry!  I'll try another approach.  However, mind what MaxU commented.

Answer (score 2):

alternative solution:

```
In [352]: s[pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index).isin([1,2,3]).all(1)]
Out[352]:
1    [1, 2, 3]
dtype: object
```

step-by-step:

```
In [353]: pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index)
Out[353]:
   0  1  2
1  1  2  3
2  4  5  6

In [354]: pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index).isin([1,2,3])
Out[354]:
       0      1      2
1   True   True   True
2  False  False  False

In [355]: pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index).isin([1,2,3]).all(1)
Out[355]:
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```